# Register tabStateChange event via javascript in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Is there a supported way to register tabStateChange events in javascript via the Xrm.Page API rather than through the form UI, similar to addOnChange for attributes?  Something like:

```
Xrm.Page.getControl("controlname").addTabStateChange(function(){});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  I am not 100% sure it's supported, but it is certainly possible.  Here's an example:

```
Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get(0).add_tabStateChange(function(){alert('test')})
```

Comment: Thank you Paul.  Out of curiosity how did you find that as my crawling of the sdk docs and MSDN turned up nothing.  I'd come to the conclusion that you can't register events against any form controls (tab, sections, iframe) via js.

Comment: Well it may not be in the SDK (which is why I say it's probably not 100% supported); however, it is available.  To find it, I used IE Developer tools and the console.  If you are unfamiliar, here's a mini little intro: http://blog.customereffective.com/blog/2012/02/xrm-2011-javascript-another-101-lesson.html

Comment: Further to that, when it comes to the Xrm variable, this MSDN link is useful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334351.aspx

Comment: Didn't work for me (on CRM365). I get this error: "Object doesn't support property or method 'add_tabStateChange' at Form_onload" :(

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, this is now fully supported in UCI.  The syntax can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/formcontext-ui-tabs

Here's a snippet that should do the trick.  This is supported.

```
formContext.ui.tabs.get("tabname").addTabStateChange(function() { alert("test") } );
```

A quick note - this registers the function when the tab state changes, so this anonymous function may get registered multiple times if the tab is changing state multiple times.